# How to alter more that one user using ALTER USER in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to change `DEFAULT TABLESPACE` for all users except for `SYS`.

```
select username from DBA_USERS where username!='SYS';
```

gets me all users I need.

But I do not know how to properly integrate this subquery to alter user.

I tried

```
ALTER USER (select username from DBA_USERS where username!='SYS') DEFAULT TABLESPACE DATA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to write a PL/SQL script which will loop through all users you want and - using dynamic SQL - alter each of these users. Something like this:

What do I have?

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL>
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

I won't change default tablespace for all users, just for `scott` and `mike`. You'd omit line #6.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select username from all_users
  5                  where username <> 'SYS'
  6                    and username in ('SCOTT', 'MIKE')
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_Str := 'alter user ' || cur_r.username ||
 10               ' default tablespace users';
 11      dbms_output.put_line('User: ' || cur_r.username);
 12      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 13      execute immediate l_str;
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
User: MIKE
alter user MIKE default tablespace users
User: SCOTT
alter user SCOTT default tablespace users

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Another (maybe simpler?) option is to let SQL create bunch of statements for you:

```
SQL> select 'alter user ' || username || ' default tablespace users;' stmt
  2  from all_users
  3  where username <> 'SYS'
  4    and username in ('SCOTT', 'MIKE');

STMT
-------------------------------------------------------------------
alter user MIKE default tablespace users;
alter user SCOTT default tablespace users;

SQL>
```

Now you'd **copy** these `ALTER USER ...` lines and **paste** them and - that's it. Or, you could **spool** result of that `SELECT` into a file (e.g. `alter_file.sql`) and then run the file as

```
SQL> @alter_file
```

So yes, there are other options, but such a PL/SQL does everything for you *at once*, you don't have to do anything afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I started writing the procedure but I believed there was a faster way. And apparently ou can not change XS$NULL user.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info; have a look.